# Using two hard drives for a laptop, one at a time

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

So I've got a rather puny 50 GB HDD in my laptop. I just got a 250GB SSD that I'm going to install Windows 7 using the same Product Key that is tied to that laptop, essentially giving me 2 hard drives with the same Windows install on them. I've put everything that I believe is essential on to a flash drive (from the 50GB) to migrate it onto the SSD after the install, but if I find I overlooked something, would it be possible to put the original 50 gigger back in to get anything else and then reboot with the SSD to save it? I know I could get one of them fancy cables and hook it up to my USB, but I was wondering if I could just boot it up with whichever hard drive I choose whenever the need arised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can put the original drive back in to get stuff off of it. Windows *might* no longer be activated after activating on the SSD, but normally this shouldn't affect you. Even if it does, you should be able to boot and use the computer unactivated for a short time. And if you had any issues, you would still have the option to buy an external drive enclosure and access the HDD from the SSD installation.

Comment: Windows doesn't lose it's activation just because you took the drive out.  So long as the hardware is similar enough it works.  I've popped an old drive in before to get data out of the registry--something that's not easy to do with it mounted externally.

Comment: What I mean by that is that if the old installation connects to the internet it might discover that another installation was activated with the same key and invalidate itself. Haven't tested this though.

Comment: It didn't cause me any trouble when I did it although the old drive wasn't in for long.  I just needed a license key and then swap back.

Comment: Well, I just tried doing a clean install onto the blank SSD and even though I double- and triple-checked the Product Key, the installation says it's invalid. Apparently, the install DVD I'm using isn't the right one to use.

Comment: Think I found my error: the laptop originally had XP installed on it--the PK I was using was for that. Gonna throw the original HDD in and get the Win7 PK...

Comment: Nope. Win7 PK has "-OEM-" in it along with zeros. Activation doesn't allow entering zeros into the PK, so I guess I'm dead in the water...guess I'll need to get one of them fancy cables and clone my HDD instead...
I hope that works.....

Comment: You can search for a utility that can show you the original product key, but I can't vouch for the legitimacy of any particular one.

Comment: According to Window's Validation program, my copy is genuine, so I guess I'm good to go... probably find out in three days.